# What is a RECORD data type belong to in sql and how can I convert it to FLOAT?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I browse a table schema I found one of the column data types was (RECORD) data type
I don't have any feedback about this value type so neither CAST nor  CONVERT work with it
kindly how can I solve this problem?

Comment: A [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)) is a compound data type; you won't be able to _cast_ it to a single value, you will need to _extract_ the relevant value. To get more help than that, you'll have to provide more details: Are you seeing this in BigQuery itself, or in a source database you're trying to import? What do the values in the columns look like? Why do you want a float in particular?

Comment: To quickly add to this, if you expand the record in the schema browser (by clicking the little triangle/arrow), you will be able to see the fields inside the record.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering me, I wanna combine multiple tables into one table by using the UNION statement.To make unique columns  I have to convert this column to FLOAT to be compatible with the same column in other tables.

Comment: A record is not a field/column, but rather a collection of fields/columns, so unioning a field and a record will not be possible.  You either need to extract the relevant field from the record to join to your original table, or place the original field into a mostly-empty record/struct to match your table with the record.